# How to 'pull' content used in Marketo email marketing campaigns to a portal, what are the options?

Tags: marketo

I would like to 'pull' content used in Marketo email marketing campaigns to a portal so we can display as news / content etc.

I gather that it cannot be done with the API, what other options could be used to pull or push content to our portal?

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta Asset API (REST) which allows you to retrieve the email's HTML. You can search for emails, retrieve their metadata, and download the email's HTML. Contact technical support to ask to be added to the beta program. Since it's a beta program, there is no support yet. The API will be final later this year (I don't know exact timing), so you may also want to wait for that.

Comment: We are looking into getting on the program, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh mentioned, Marketo recently released an [Asset API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/) that would enable this use case.

First, you would use the [Get Emails endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/get-emails) to get a list of emails in Marketo. Then, you would use the [Get Email Content by Id endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/get-email-content-by-id) to get the content associated with those emails.